# Find the Volume .

Tags: calculus, integration, volume

Find the volume of $(x/3)^2 + (y/3)^2 + (z/2)^2 = 36$ bounded by  $x^2 + y^2 - 2y = 0$ and the plane $z=0$. was an exercise on my exams and im not sure i got it right. Sorry if im making you do the calculations but i wanted to see if there is an easy way to calculate it or it has lots and lots of arithmetic operations .

Comment: Maybe using a different coordinate system would simplify the double integral.

Comment: Do you mean $(x/3)^2_(y/3)^2+(z/2)^2=36$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint**
let $x=18\rho\cos\theta\sin\phi$ , $y=18\rho\sin\theta\sin\phi$ and $z=12\rho\cos\phi$
we have 
$$dz\,dx\,dy=3888\,\rho^2\sin\phi\,d\rho\,d\phi\,d\theta$$
and
$${{\left( \frac{x}{3} \right)}^{2}}+{{\left( \frac{y}{3} \right)}^{2}}+{{\left( \frac{z}{2} \right)}^{2}}=36\Leftrightarrow \,{{\rho }^{2}}=1$$